# Populate data extension with SH-256 encrypted email addresses

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, encryption

I have a project where I need to deliver hashed email addresses to a vendor for the purposes of data matching.  The vendor accepts SHA-256 hashed emails.  Is there a way to populate a data extension with hashed emails using this process?  I've seen a reply to this inquiry using a ampscript in a content block + SSJS activity in automation studio but curious if there is more detail on how this approach would work?

thx
Paul

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend not taking this approach for a number of reasons:

1. SSJS doesn't support SHA256 hashing, so you'll need to switch between SSJS and AMPScript that has SHA256 support. This gives rise to a large performance overhead.
2. You'll be looping through a large number of records row-by-row, rather than performing a bulk operation. That's slow.
3. You'll be making a significant number of API calls to retrieve records from your Data Extension. SFMC API's aren't the fastest, so you're incurring significant overhead with each page of data you're retrieving.
4. You'll be making a large number of individual updates/upserts to your Data Extension to store your hashed email values. Yet more processing and overhead.

That said, here's an example of iterating through the records in a Data Extension, calculating a SHA256 hash of the email address and storing the value back in the Data Extension;

```
<script runat="server">
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy()
    var deName = 'EmailHashes';
    var hasMoreRows = true;
    var reqId;

    var cols = ["SubscriberKey","EmailAddress"];

    do {
        var resp;
        if (!reqId){
            resp = prox.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + deName + "]", cols)
        } else {
            resp = prox.getNextBatch("DataExtensionObject[" + deName + "]", reqId);
        }

        if(resp.Results){
            hasMoreRows = resp.HasMoreRows || false;
            reqId = resp.RequestID;

            for (var i = 0; i < resp.Results.length; i++) {
                var row = resp.Results[i];
                var subscriberKey,email;
                for (var p = 0; p < row.Properties.length; p++) {
                    var prop = row.Properties[p];
                    if (prop.Name=="EmailAddress") email = prop.Value;
                    if (prop.Name=="SubscriberKey") subscriberKey = prop.Value;
                }

                var SSJSHash = Platform.Function.TreatAsContent('%%=SHA256("'+email+'")=%%');
                var updated = Platform.Function.UpsertDE(deName,["SubscriberKey"],[subscriberKey],["SSJSHash"],[SSJSHash]);
            }
        } else {
            hasMoreRows = false;
        }
    } while (hasMoreRows);
</script>
```

My recommended approach would be to do this as a bulk operation using a SQL Query Activity in Automation Studio. This scales far better and is unlikely to give rise to the type of timeout errors you'd encounter with processing large numbers of records with SSJS. The result is just the same.

```
SELECT
    SubscriberKey,
    EmailAddress,
    LOWER(
        CONVERT(
            NVARCHAR(MAX),
            HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',
                CONVERT(varchar(254),EmailAddress)
                )
        ,2)
    ) as SQLHash
FROM 
    EmailHashes WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: SQL Query is definitely the way to go, it is most performant and efficient

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you so much for the help